# Javascript gets loaded correctly in QA but not when debugging in Development Environment [ASP.NET]

Tags: javascript, asp.net, runtime-error, visual-studio-debugging

I have a client side validation script that is written on OnKeyPress event for a textbox which blocks the user to enter only numbers as below.

```
function allow_only_onkeypress(e, allow) {
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape") == -1) {
        var ch = String.fromCharCode(window.event.keyCode);
        window.event.returnValue = (allow.indexOf(ch) >= 0);
    } else {
        var ch = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        return (allow.indexOf(ch) >= 0);
    }
}

function digits_only_onkeypress(e) {
    return allow_only_onkeypress(e, "0123456789\r");
}
```

The above code is available in Common.js which is common and gets loaded in header.asp(Common template). In QA Environment (published code), this method is properly loaded and validation works as expected. But When debugging the same code it throws an error as below,

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: The value of the property 'digits_only_onkeypress' is null or undefined, not a Function object.
```

The javascript function is not loaded on the current page while debugging. Is this the way, the javascript code usually works or is there something that i can change to resolve this issue.

**Update:**
The issue is resolved, since the environment which i was looking for holds the javascript that is in cache. After cleating the cache, it worked.

Comment: Look for 404 errors in the debug console (network tab).  It's probably trying to include something that's not in the same place locally.

Comment: No @Archer , i could not find any 404 errors in the Network tab. Thanks for responding. But i found out the issue. This is due to the silly error in Development environment code that referred to an Old Js code which doesn't have the changes made in QA.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out :)